# Java Hibernate INHERITANCE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

Here is a basic drawing for my problem.

[image: Description of my problem]

So I have a Person class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "PERSON_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name="PERSON_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PERSON_ID_SEQ")
    private Long personId;
    
    private String name;
}
```

and for example a Police class that is inherited from a Person.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "POLICE_MAN")
public class PoliceMan extends Person{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "police_id")
    private Long policeId;
    
    private String something;
}
```

So the problem is, I can't use @Id annotation in PoliceMan because I have one in the Person class. How could I solve that? How can a police_id be an uniqu identifier?

Thanks for help.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

I tried something from that page, but ...

Comment: You already have a unique identifier, why do you think you need another?

Comment: It might be more accurate to associate it with a foreign key. You can establish a One To One relationship between Person and PoliceMan.

Comment: Your table structure doesn't show a FK from police->person. Nothing stops you from having a police_id attribute within your entity, it just can't be marked as THE id. You can have any number of unique identifiers within entities and tables - just mark the column with a uniqueness constraint. Plus one on this shouldn't be using inheritance despite that though. An officer (PoliceMan) is a role, not a defining characteristic of a person, and you'll have issues maintaining their existence as a person if it isn't separated out, just as you apparently are for the table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It might be more accurate to associate it with a foreign key. You can establish a One To One relationship between Person and PoliceMan."

"our table structure doesn't show a FK from police->person. Nothing stops you from having a police_id attribute within your entity, it just can't be marked as THE id. You can have any number of unique identifiers within entities and tables - just mark the column with a uniqueness constraint. Plus one on this shouldn't be using inheritance despite that though. An officer (PoliceMan) is a role, not a defining characteristic of a person, and you'll have issues maintaining their existence as a person if it isn't separated out, just as you apparently are for the table data."

Thanks you all have right.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the Inheritance mapping. Just extending the Person class is not a JPA inheritance. By looking at your code I suppose that you wanted to make a joined table inheritance, because you tried to map each entity to a different table.

To do so you have to use the **@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)** annotation on the PoliceMan class.

Also you should use the **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "person_id")** annotation on the PoliceMan class. This indicates that the PK of the PoliceMan entity is person_id and it has a foreign key constraint to the PK of the Person. **Remove the policeId field**. With the annotations above you already have the **person_id** column in both of your tables (you don't have to declare an id in your PoliceMan class).

So if you do it manually on SQL side you have to create a person_id primary key column in PERSON table and also in POLICE_MAN table, and you should have a foreign key in POLICE_MAN table on person_id column that references the person_id column of the PERSON table.